# Will replacing the MOC3024 with MOC3021 make any change

Tags: arduino, ac, opto-isolator, triac

I'm student of 10th grade and new to electronics I'm trying to make a switch to control appliances which runs on AC mains and I don't want to use any relay
 see the circuit diagram from the link to instructables below but I'm facing the problem that presently I have MOC3021 other than MOC3041 and it is used in the circuit so can I use MOC3021 in place of MOC3041?

http://m.instructables.com/id/Small-Triac-Switch/

Sorry for my english.

Comment: First, google for the datasheets and read them. Secondly, there are (non-grammatical) errors in your posting- what is a MOC3024? If you are not more careful with mains wiring than you are with your typing, you could be injured or worse.

Comment: Alright I've tested it and it is working

Comment: But do you now understand how it works differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is "For loads of 10 watts or less; yes, it will work. For loads greater than 10 watts, don't do it."

The MOC3041 is rated for 1 amp, which is ~120 watts at 120 VAC. The MOC3021 is rated for 100 mA, which is ~12 watts. For loads less than this, either unit will work. For loads greater than this, at some point the MOC3021 will fail. Or rather, there is no guarantee the MOC3021 will work at these levels, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

MOC3041 is identical to the MOC3021 except that 3041 triggers at the zero crossingpoint.